# How to move files in a pythonic way?

Tags: python, glob, shutil

First, sorry for the long post.

I need to move .xlsx files from the previous days from one folder to another, but i shoudnt move the files with today date, just the files from previous days.

In my current code, i am moving the files by specifying each one of them with a Minus X days, but i think the code is not in the best 'shape' nor the best performance/quality

```
import datetime,os, glob, shutil
from pathlib import Path

dir_carteiras = r"C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras"
test = os.listdir(dir_carteiras)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".jpg"):
        os.remove( os.path.join(dir_carteiras, item))

#get todays  date and a calculation for today -1 day
today=datetime.date.today()
minus_one_day=datetime.timedelta(days=-1)

#use the calculation to get previous 5 days strings
d_N1=today+minus_one_day
d_N1_ = d_N1.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
d_N2=d_N1+minus_one_day
d_N3=d_N2+minus_one_day
d_N4=d_N3+minus_one_day
d_N5=d_N4+minus_one_day

#format dates for the files formats
Date_Carteira_N1 = d_N1.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
Date_Carteira__0 = today.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
Date_Carteira_N2 =d_N2.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
Date_Carteira_N3 =d_N3.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
Date_Carteira_N4 =d_N4.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
Date_Carteira_N5 =d_N5.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
Alocacao_0 = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')
Alocacao_N1 = d_N1.strftime('%Y%m%d')
Alocacao_N2 = d_N2.strftime('%Y%m%d')
Alocacao_N3 = d_N3.strftime('%Y%m%d')
Alocacao_N4 = d_N4.strftime('%Y%m%d')
Alocacao_N5 = d_N5.strftime('%Y%m%d')

#folder destination
NewFolderPath = dir_carteiras+"\Historico"
Path(NewFolderPath).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

#Move the "Carteira" files from previous 5 days
Carteiras_move_N1 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Date_Carteira_N1+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Carteiras_move_N1:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)
Carteiras_move_N2 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Date_Carteira_N2+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Carteiras_move_N2:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)
Carteiras_move_N3 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Date_Carteira_N3+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Carteiras_move_N3:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)
Carteiras_move_N4 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Date_Carteira_N4+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Carteiras_move_N4:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)
Carteiras_move_N5 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Date_Carteira_N5+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Carteiras_move_N5:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)

#Move the "Alocacao" files from the previous 5 days
Alocacao_move_N1 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Alocacao_N1+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Alocacao_move_N1:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)
Alocacao_move_N2 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Alocacao_N2+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Alocacao_move_N2:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)
Alocacao_move_N3 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Alocacao_N3+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Alocacao_move_N3:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)
Alocacao_move_N4 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Alocacao_N4+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Alocacao_move_N4:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)
Alocacao_move_N5 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Carteiras\*'+Alocacao_N5+'.xlsx', recursive=True)
for f in Alocacao_move_N5:
        shutil.move(f,NewFolderPath)
```

EDIT with Tylerr's answer try:

```
import os
import shutil
from datetime import datetime

dir_carteiras = r"C:\Users\GuilhermeMachado\Documents\Carteiras"
test = os.listdir(dir_carteiras)
NewFolderPath = dir_carteiras+"\Historico"

datetime_object = datetime.now()
today = datetime_object.day
month = datetime_object.month
year = datetime_object.year

for file in list(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(dir_carteiras))):
    unix_time = os.path.getmtime(file)
    date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_time)
    date_day = int(date.strftime("%d"))
    date_month = int(date.strftime("%m"))
    date_year = int(date.strftime("%Y"))
    if date_day < today or date_month < month or date_year < year:
        shutil.move(file, NewFolderPath)
```

Comment: any variables with patterns: `a1` `a2` `a3` ... is very bad practice in any language. So before you made this "pythonic" fix that.

Comment: This code works — correct? — and you just want to know how to improve it? There's a separate site for that named [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, i will start doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after something like this maybe?

```
import os
import shutil
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.now()
today = datetime_object.day
month = datetime_object.month
year = datetime_object.year

for file in list(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir())):
    unix_time = os.path.getmtime(file)
    date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_time)
    date_day = int(date.strftime("%d"))
    date_month = int(date.strftime("%m"))
    date_year = int(date.strftime("%Y"))
    if date_day < today or date_month < month or date_year < year:
        shutil.move(file, NewFolderPath)
```

Comment: But this would move all files in folder, even with today's date, right? I should not move todays files

Comment: No you see the `if date < today:`, so if the date the file was created is 15th and today is 16th, it will move it, but if the file is created on the 16th and today is the 16th, it will not.

Comment: Also, you might want to do the same thing I do with dates but with months and years because it wont automatically do that; it only does it by dates as of now.

Comment: How do i change the path from the files to be moved from?

Comment: Inside the `os.listdir()` on `for file in list(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir())):` just define a string with the path.

Comment: What i changed: `for file in list(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(dir_carteiras))):`     `date = int(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_time).strftime("%d_%m_%Y"))`

Comment: No it should only be `.strftime("%d")`, you will need to have separate variables for month and year and have separate if statements for each of those too, i'll update my answer.

Comment: I inserted the `dir_carteiras` in to  `os.listdir` , run the conde but nothing were moved.

Comment: in dir_carteiras path i have 3 files, one from 21/02/2020, one from 13/02/2020 and one from today, still 3 files in path.

Comment: No need to be sorry, but same result were given with new edit

Comment: I added my try with your code to the question, anything is wrong?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me; have you set the path correctly?

Comment: Yes, path is correct. Here is a sample of a file name: Carteira_X_Y_Z_28_01_2020.xlsx

Comment: You can try replacing os.listdir with glob.glob if you would like

Comment: `for file in list(....):`  use of `list` here is an overkill and obsolete.

Comment: No, you're incorrect. Filter here actually returns a object which can not be iterated over how we wish to.